# Passing generic type to non generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, methods, generic-type-argument

I was wondering how to mix calls of specifically typed methods, when coming from a generically typed method?

I know the example given is redudant. It is for illustration purposes only. What I imagine would be a minimal comprehensive context would be as follow:

> The method `BitConverter.GetBytes` has multiple overloads for value-types. But if I were to code a method that goes `static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T value) where T : struct` that would return `BitConverter.GetBytes(value)`, I get an error message saying that the best overloaded match for has some invalid arguments.

I guess this has to do with value being of generic type instead of specific.

Is there any way to give generic types to non-generic methods ? Via some casting trick or anything ?

Comment: Write a method for each of the types you're interested in.

Comment: Overloads and generic parameters are very different things. Generic parameters are a constrained contract, that's to say there is an implicit knowledge about their signatures. overloads are targeted

Comment: The overload is chosen at compile time, not at runtime. So only one specific overload must be chosen, you can't say "choose some overload based on actual type this value will have at runtime".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for now.
you should costrain the generic type to something the compiler can narrow down to one of the overloads of the BitConverter.GetBytes(value). The struct you used to constrain is a very larger group than just one of the overloads, so it won't let you proceed.

With c#10 you might have one chance with the feature 'extend everything', but it's not yet released won't have much sense to talk about that now.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Your answer leads me to believe that using `where T : double` for example woudl then work but it doesn't and yields the same error. What am I missing in my understanding ?

Comment: it would work if that was possible, a constraint must be an interface... the language is about the rules who wrote and mantain it gave to it.

A constraint to a specific type defy the purpose of generics. so there is no reason to write or let someone write that.
watch closely if you try to write that the error changes in : double is not a valid constraint

Comment: look, i don't know what are you trying to accomplish, but from the example and the question itself looks like you are trying to change the framework. which is a lot of work (unpaid) you should use it instead! 

If it's about understanding, i would go with some better examples, polymorphism is a complicated subject, deep diving in it isn't a great way to get to understand it, i suggest you start seeing it as a tool, and get to understand it while using it.

Comment: @CrumbleZ `where T : someStruct` doesn't make sense, because it leads to only one possible type